# Laravel 8: How to download file in storage folder?

Tags: laravel-8

I have this function

```
  public function download($id){
    $path = storage_path('app/public/file.pdf');
    return respone()->download($path);
 }
```

and the path of `file.pdf` is in `storage/app/public/file.pdf`

I have this error in my function.

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\respone()

I don't know what is wrong, but this is the exact code he used.

Comment: you have typo error respone() .It should be response()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an error on the return function; replace `respone()` to `response()`.